# How to make FSCalendar selected date code

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am using FSCalendar and HealthKit. (On top calendar, on bottom healthkit)

If I touch specific date, then the step count for the day will show on bottom.

I am struggling to make 'selected date'.

Could you check how to improve the code attached below?

```
func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, didSelect date: Date, at monthPosition: FSCalendarMonthPosition) {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        ///formatter.dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-dd"
        let startDate = formatter.string(from: date)
        let endDate = formatter.string(from: date+1)
    }
```

I've been reading through the FSCalendar documentation

but I could not find anything

so I made the code but still being anxious.